# Adding custom jquery to meanjs yeoman generator

Tags: jquery, angularjs, yeoman, meanjs

I would like to know if there is a way to include custom jquery to the meanjs yeoman generator.   The public folder has serval sub-folders and files in it that seem to be there only for including angular and css files. I am not sure where a custom jquery file should go and how it should be wired up to the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the script into the folder `public/lib/` then if you go to the `config/env/all.js` and open that file there will be an `assets` section in there you will then need to add `public/lib/name of jquery file.js` to that array of javascript files. It should look something like the below

```
assets: {
    lib: {
        css: [
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        ],
        js: [
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            // Add yours here
        ]
    } 
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do that and a simple console.log("test"), prints test in the console. However, when I am trying to include selectors with the $document.ready() wrapper, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error. I am thinking I should reference the jquery cdn somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: Looking at the `lib` folder it does have jquery in there but it doesn't seem to be referenced in the assets section I posted in the answer. I added `public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js` to the list of files that were posted above, as long as you then put your custom jquery file after it in that list it should work fine and you should no longer get the "Uncaught ReferenceError".

Comment: What I wanted to do was manipulate the home view's DOM from that file. However, that is not working. How would you control your DOM specifically (for example: if I wanted to do $("h1").remove()), which removes all the h1 tags from the the home page, how would I link the jquery file which is doing that to the particular view I want the changes to happen in.

Comment: You would have to define the function to do the dom manipulation somewhere, you could create a service that has a function that removes all h1 tags for example. And inject that into the angular controller for the page you want to do the DOM manipulation on. A small sample is shown here: http://jsbin.com/fufomitojo/2/edit